# Expectation of $||P_VY||^2$

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, projection-matrices, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Given that $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2I)$ where $\mu\in V$ ($V$ is a vector space with $\dim(V)=p$. If $P_V$ is the projection matrix of $Y$ on $V$ then, we define
$$\hat{\mu}=P_VY.$$
Then,
$$E(||\hat{\mu}||^2)=E(\hat{\mu}'\hat{\mu})=E(Y'P_V'P_VY).$$
Until this, I understand what they're doing. What formula was used for the next step? It's probably a basic formula that I can't recall right now-

> $$E(||\hat{\mu}||^2)=E(Y'P_V'P_VY)=\mu'P_V\mu+\text{trace}(P_V\sigma^2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for a random vector $X$ with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$, and some fixed (symmetric) matrix $A$,
$$
E (X^T A X) = \text{tr}(A \Sigma) + \mu^T A \mu.
$$
If this is an orthogonal projection, then $P$ is symmetric, and so $P^T P = P^2 = P$, the final equality holding because projections are idempotent.

Comment: $A$ need not be symmetric or idempotent for the result to hold, right?

Comment: @zaira it should be symmetirc (i updated my answer to make that clear). It need not be idempotent though, I only added that to explain the result in the final line of your question