# $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $X'PX$ follows?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4535937/562589) that went unanswered, but managed to figure that what I need is something to do with the following.

If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $P$ is an idempotent matrix. Then what can be said about the distribution of $X'PX$? If not distribution, then what about expectation and variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic result is this: if $\mathbf{X}$ is a random vector such that $\mathbf{X}\sim \text{Multivariate Normal}(\mathbf{0},I)$, and $P$ is an idempotent matrix, then
$$\mathbf{X}^TP \mathbf{X}\sim \chi^2\ \ \text{with tr}(P)\ \ \text{d.f.}$$
in which tr$(P)$ is the trace of matrix $P$.